# Complex Gaussian interal high dimension

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am having hard time to figure out if there is a way to get a close-form of the following integral:

$\int_{\mathbb{C}^N} \frac{1}{(\bar{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{v})^N} \exp(-(\bar{\mathbf{u}}-\bar{\mathbf{v}})\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}))d\mathbf{v}$

where $\mathbf{D}$ is a real diagonal matrix with strictly positive term and the vector $\mathbf{u}$ is complex.

Does one of you have any idea how to maybe connect this integral to known form ?

Thank you in advance to all who might post.

John

Comment: is there no intgration over $d\bar{v}$?

Comment: No there is no such integration over $d\bar{\mathbf{v}}$. Would it have made the integral easier to calculate ?

Comment: Typically you integrate over $dvd\bar{v}$. in which context this integral arises?
Note that you can threat $dv$ and $d\bar{v}$ as independet variables. this should. make your life much easier..

Comment: It arises in a context of marginalization of $\mathbf{v}$. I initially have a joint density $f(a,\mathbf{v})$ and in order to marginalize with respect to  $\mathbf{v}$ I have to compute something of the form I wrote.

Comment: the measure is then $d\vec{v}=dv_1dv_2...dv_i$ right?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is

Comment: Ok, then i have some doubts about the convergence at $v=0$, what can we say about that?